# Mixing Kentucky Blue Grass and Tall Fescue

Tags: landscaping, grass

Hello all I am renovating my backyard and about 85% of it has become pure dirt.

I am located in southern PA and began the process of planting grass seed.

I began by seeding the entire backyard with Kentucky Blue Grass... A few days later I came to the realization I probably should have used a tall fescue instead.

My question is:

- can I reseed the entire backyard with Tall Fescue creating a mix of the two?

Comment: Of course you can do this, but what is your concern?

Comment: I am probably just being paranoid but the front yard is a fescue (the two are separated by a fence) so I wasn't sure if a mixture would look better vs pure KBG. I was also concerned with growth - if maybe I would have more success with a mixture vs pure KBG. It's also worth calling out I am no seasoned veteran if you can already tell :)

Comment: Are you referring to old school field type fescues or the newer turf type?   I have a mix of KGB and turf type and I actually regret overseeding the fescue.  I wish is was all uniform and it would just go dormant at the same time.  The clumping habit of the fescue is a pain when it comes to edging the sidewalks.

Answer (score 1):

Different cultivars have different growth habits: some turn green early in the season while others are still dormant; some hold their green during the hottest part of summer while others die back during that period, etc. It's not uncommon for a turf to be a blend of cultivars. I believe the blend I used was a mix of a fescue, KBG, and maybe some rye grass..?

The blend for a specific area might vary depending on the specific attributes sought if it is professionally designed for a specific application (a high end sports field, or a golf course, perhaps). For a home it's probably an unscientific "some of this, some of that" or a professionally-designed general-purpose blend. I couldn't say whether the bagged products at national-name home centers use the same blends across the nation or are mixed based on regional-level climate norms.

Comment: It sounds like in my situation mixing is ok.. it's a common practice based on the overall end goal. Granted I am no professional so I can only speculate what the mix will bring me - but it sounds like there is no genuine concern or issues with my original question.